# Subscriber data not up to date

Tags: kinect, queue, camera, image, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a subscriber to one of the image topics and I have set my buffer to 1 using:

subscriber =rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed",CompressedImage, callback,  queue_size=1)

However my subscriber still lags behind. Any idea what might be causing this? Am I setting the queue size correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195186/subscriber-data-not-up-to-date/) by [Giza](https://answers.ros.org/users/19792/giza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-10-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-16**:
How much lag are you seeing? How are you measuring it?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-10-17**:
Does it also lag if you display the pointcloud in RViz?

**Comment by [Giza](https://answers.ros.org/users/19792/giza/) on 2014-10-17**:
@ahendrix Its about 5 to 10 seconds of lag. Basically when I look at the screen it shows images of things that happened 5 to 10 swconds ago.

**Comment by [Giza](https://answers.ros.org/users/19792/giza/) on 2014-10-17**:
@BennyRe I tried it on on image_view and theres no lag but that is because I do a lot of processing on the image before I display it (cv2.imshow) . Now I cannot process at the rate that the publisher is publishing and so what I want to do is drop any messages that arrive while I am processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like the lag you're seeing is caused by the image processing that you're doing.

If you're seeing one new image displayed by your algorithm every 5-10 seconds, then it's probably working properly, and the lag you see is the result of your processing time.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Giza](https://answers.ros.org/users/19792/giza/) on 2014-10-17**:
That's right! And by the time Im done processing some time would have passed!! So in terms of viewing the data Ill always be behind..